# DotNetNuke Pros and cons for community blogging site

Tags: dotnetnuke, blogs

I'm evaluating DotNetNuke for a project in which an offshore team is going to be doing the development. In short, the application will be a community blogging platform with many similarities to stackoverflow except no questions, just posts. Posts may include an image or video, tags, use info, title, body, community vote (up or down) comments, hotness, and a few other details. They should be taggable, sortable, categorizeable (beyond what a single set of tags provide) In the future the site will carry forums, a calendar, and a couple of other features for which there are modules available for DotNetNuke. Additionally, this site will incorporate a user experience that will include a lot of custom skinning.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm considering using it as well, but more for a customized company portal.  I've heard the codebase was a mess, but that was years ago, I'd like to know if the most recent version has been cleaned up, organized.

Comment: Hey Neil, the short answer regarding if its been cleaned up is "yes" but I would highly recommend grabbing the source from Codeplex, fire up VS and spend a little time with it yourself. The latest version (DNN 5) included a pretty large-scale refactoring of the code base.

Comment: In short, I would not select DotNetNuke for a any new project. Shockingly, DNN's blogging capabilities out of the box are pretty poor. You'll likely need to pay for one of the blogging modules if you want anything even remotely close to what Wordpress/Drupal offers out of the box. I have over 20 DNN projects under my belt and I've been using it since its beta nearly 2 decades ago. I used to love it, but I grown to despise it for multiple reasons. There are just such better options out there and so many drawback of DNN at this point in time. [See my full rant on DNN here](https://siteden.com/do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a web application framework (such as DotNetNuke) has a ton of benefits to help you get up and running faster and do *less work* when creating custom functionality.

However, you have to realize that you're basically incorporating tons of code into your project that you may not be familiar with. No matter how good the code is and how easy the framework is to learn, there's still going to be a significant learning curve for you and your team.

Your decision making process (if you're still deciding whether or not to use DotNetNuke), should include (in addition to reading, talking and other general investigation):

- Downloading the application from Codeplex and checking out the source.
- Investigating the third party modules that are out there.
- Downloading a free module or two that comes with source, and try to reverse engineer the creator's development process. How did she integrate with the framework, what features did she take advantage of, what was written from scratch?

One place where DotNetNuke (or any other framework with tons of extensions) available can really shine is taking existing extensions that are available and customize them. If you need to implement a given feature, check out the solutions in the third party extension community first. You can probably find one that gets you a good percentage of the way there and use it as a foundation for your feature.

For example, if you want a photo gallery on your site, you probably don't want to write it from scratch. There are three major photo galleries out there that sell the source code. The core gallery module is free, simple gallery is cheap, and the source for ultra media gallery is available for a reasonable amount compared to writing it yourself. Any of these could give you a good head start in implementing your features.